# Обьясните в общем терминологию в Android

Tags: android, терминология

Вот вижу я, например, разные примеры кода в андроиде: onЧтототам и onЧтототамResult. Можете обьяснить простым языком, что в общем это означает?

Comment: Названия функций, вы бы конкретный пример кода скинули, для примера поищите "Жизненный цикл андроид", почитайте, когда данные функции вызываются, что деллают

Comment: Например onLogin и onLoginResult

Comment: Это означает, что данные методы так называются. Больше это не означает совершенно ничего.

Comment: Вы, возможно, смотрели какую то библиотеку или что-то типо того. Нужен код и желательно знать откуда он, что бы определить что они делают, как работают и тд. Мб это библиотека от Google, мб код Васи Пупкина, кто знает. А если вы о синтаксике, то это для удобства , есть Java Convention , там написаны правила оформления кода

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае:

приставка *on-* к методу означает, что данный метод - колбэк (возвращает результат какого то события из другого класса)

приставка *set-*  означает, что этот метод устанавливет значение

приставка *get-* означает, что метод возвращает значение

приставка *is-* означает, что метод возвращает булево значение о состоянии

но в частном случае любое название метода, это просто имя, которое придумал программист и оно может вообще ничего не значить.

Чтобы быть уверенным о назначении метода и смысла передаваемых ему аргументов с возвращаемыми значениями, нужно, в первую очередь, **смотреть документацию** (если она есть, а для фреймворка Android она очень подробная), javadoc класса,  комментарии в коде к методу или сами исходники ...

Имя метода, это в общем то, последний рубеж что то узнать о его назначении, хотя, конечно, проф.программисты и в имя вкладывают определенную информацию о его назначении, но нет такой гарантии, что имя такое то, значит определенно делает то то.

Comment: А если onЧтототамResult? Например onLoginResult

Comment: onЧтототамResult -видимо колбэк (так как с on-), который  возвращает результат обращения к другому классу, в данном случае результат попытки залогиниться (какой-нибудь токен, предоставленные привилегии или что сочтет нужным), опять же в каждом конкретном случае он может делать все что угодно.